# Django syncdb error for blog tables

Tags: python, database, django, psycopg2

i'm following this tutorial: http://www.programmersbook.com/page/21/Django-Beginner-Tutorial-Part-I/

and I added the database details (running django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2) and i added the template dirs. But when i do

```
./manage.py syncdb
```

i get:

```
    self.connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Permission denied
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Any suggestions on how i can fix this please?

Answer (score 0):

Before connecting to database you need to install database server, and configure it for any user to access.

If you want just follow tutorial use SQLite -it's most simple to configure.

Otherwise, install database server of your choose, create database, configure access, make sure that connection details are correct, and/or DB server is up and running. 
Best way is try to connect to server via command line.

Comment: first of all, connect to server from postgres admin user, then create database, add user, configure access to database, and user's logging way.
There are lot of manuals on setting up Postgres.

Comment: is it like this: ">>> psycopg2.connect("dbname=name user=username")"

Comment: psql -U<username> -W -h ...
take a look at this
http://defindit.com/readme_files/postgres_utilities.html

Comment: i keep getting all these different errors. Can you tell me what i should do first? "su postgres" returns "su: Sorry"?

Comment: first of all, if you just want to follow tutorial, use mysqlligh, or any other existing database. 

Point is Database server should be installed, and configured before you could connect to it.

Comment: it'd be good to stick to psycopg2 for me. Can you tell me how to start?

Comment: Try to google about for "Postgres getting starting" or "Postgress installation instructions" , it's not that easy as single command.